# How can i sense the internet connectivity in a mobile application using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, connectivity

Im developing a mobile application using Xamarin.forms and i want to know if there is a way to constantly check the wifi network status to detect when the device loses connection and when it connects again
I was thinking in have a thread that every second sense the internet connection. But i dont know if maybe there another way
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: The other answer does not address the monitoring and/or event consumption part of this question, somebody please re-open question and help a fellow learner :)

Comment: Maybe the `Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged`-Event might help

Comment: Thank you both! I´m going to check the solution that is in the other post and also the library commented by @Kajot